# Why does my Rails engine need me to require it (unlike a typical gem) even if it's in the Gemfile and has require_paths configured?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-engines, gemfile

I've written a Rails engine called [annotator-store](https://github.com/itsmrwave/annotator-store). It requires an explicit `require 'annotator_store'` in the `/config/application.rb` in the main app (even if it's in the Gemfile). This baffles me because I've [written a gem before that doesn't need this to be done](https://github.com/itsmrwave/pesapal-gem).

Is this behaviour by Rails engines by design or have I missed out something?

Here's my gemspec file:

```
$:.push File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
require 'annotator_store/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name           = 'annotator-store'
  spec.version        = AnnotatorStore::VERSION
  spec.date           = Time.new.getutc.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  spec.authors        = ["Job King'ori Maina"]
  spec.email          = ['j@kingori.co']
  spec.homepage       = 'http://itsmrwave.github.io/annotator-store'
  spec.summary        = 'Rails engine to implement a Ruby backend store implementation for Annotator.'
  spec.description    = 'Rails engine to implement a Ruby backend store implementation for Annotator, an open-source JavaScript library to easily add annotation functionality to any webpage.'
  spec.license        = 'MIT'

  spec.files          = Dir['{app,config,db,lib}/**/*', 'CHANGELOG.md', 'CONTRIBUTING.md', 'LICENSE.md', 'Rakefile', 'README.md']
  spec.require_paths  = ['lib']

  spec.required_ruby_version = '>= 1.9.3'

  # Database dependencies
  spec.add_development_dependency 'mysql2'
  spec.add_development_dependency 'pg'

  # Development dependencies
  spec.add_development_dependency 'appraisal'
  spec.add_development_dependency 'database_cleaner'
  spec.add_development_dependency 'factory_girl_rails'
  spec.add_development_dependency 'faker'
  spec.add_development_dependency 'json-schema'
  spec.add_development_dependency 'rspec-rails'

  # Runtime dependencies
  spec.add_runtime_dependency 'jbuilder'
  spec.add_runtime_dependency 'rails', '>= 4.0'
end
```

You can see I've added the `lib` folder to the `require_paths`. As per the rubygems.org [gemspec documentation](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#require_paths=) ... there's a detailed write up on what `require_paths=(val)` does and that is the ...

> Paths in the gem to add to `$LOAD_PATH` when this gem is activated.

I've set up everything in the `lib` folder properly such that when you `require 'annotator_store'` everything works great.

What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is a '-' vs. '_' problem.  In Rails gem names '-' implies subdirectories, so the natural include for your engine would be 'lib/annotator.rb' and 'lib/annotator/store.rb', not 'lib/annotator_store.rb'.  So the file you expect to be required, is not.

To confirm this you can change the name of your engine, or change the file structure under 'lib'.

Comment: You were right, I incorrectly named the gem `annotator-store` when it should be `annotator_store`. I'd encourage anyone else looking at this to glance at [this link about how to 'Name your gem'](http://guides.rubygems.org/name-your-gem/) from the rubygems.org documentation for details.